# Class block does not exist

Tags: layout, magento2, block

Good morning,  I am having some trouble finding this class in the checkout/cart.For some reason this block does not exist in localhost but it those in production (Got a fresh dump from production).I have allready cleared static content , cleared cache, also I have checked if any cms or block has this class called but I cannot find the reason for it.

```
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Amasty\Mostviewed\Block\Widget\Wrapper does not exist
```

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:44]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/amasty/module-fpc-warmer/Plugin/Holepunch/BlockArguments.php:57]
#10 Amasty\Fpc\Plugin\Holepunch\BlockArguments->aroundCreateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block/Interceptor.php:23]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block\Interceptor->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:93]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:365]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:32]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:227]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:250]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php:57]
#27 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#28 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#29 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#30 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php:23]
#31 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#33 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#34 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#35 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php:32]
#36 Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#42 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/amasty/aminvisiblecaptcha/Plugin/Framework/App/FrontControllerInterface/ValidateCaptcha.php:118]
#44 Amasty\InvisibleCaptcha\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface\ValidateCaptcha->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#46 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#47 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#48 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#49 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php:23]
#50 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#51 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#52 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#53 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#54 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#55 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the exact same issue and was not sure where to find any solution for that except to retrieve the module after uninstalling it. However, today I have decided to leave the laziness and search deeper for the issue's root cause. After digging in the database, I found the following tables with data related to it (not fully purged after calling the `module:uninstall` command):

| table | column |
| --- | --- |
| admin_user | extra |
| authorization_rule | resource_id |
| cms_page | content |
| core_config_data | path |
| cron_schedule | job_code |
| layout_update | XML |
| patch_list | patch_name |

The solution is to remove the rows that are entirely related to the module itself and update the rows that include the module (for example removing the lines with the module name while giving attention to objects scope/opening&closing tags).

```
select * from [table] where [column] like '%mostviewed%';
```

I think the most important records here are the ones in `cms_page` and `layout_update` since they will be related to the frontend page rendering.